# Sublime Text 2 not auto-completing some methods

Tags: python, sublime-text-2

I'm using SublimeText2 on Ubuntu and I'm using the python gData API. My issue is that some of the variables and other stuff doesn't auto-complete. Everything above the for loop auto-completes but not anything included in the loop. Any idea why?

I installed the gData python API using the downloaded gdata tar file and ran python setup.py install.

```
import gdata.docs.service

# Create a client class which will make HTTP requests with Google Docs server.
client = gdata.docs.service.DocsService()
# Authenticate using your Google Docs email address and password.
client.ClientLogin('**@gmail.com', '**!')

# Query the server for an Atom feed containing a list of your documents.
documents_feed = client.GetDocumentListFeed()
# Loop through the feed and extract each document entry.


##Everything auto-completes except for stuff below this line


for document_entry in documents_feed.entry:
  # Display the title of the document on the command line.
  print document_entry.title.text
```

I have SublimeText CodeIntel and the Python packages installed but is there a reason that the top parts would auto-complete and not the bottom parts?

Comment: SublimeCodeIntel may be taking a while to index the associated modules. Open the console by hitting `Ctrl-\`` and scroll up looking for informative error messages. Does this still happen after restarting ST2?

Comment: This is what pops up for me when I try:

http://i.imgur.com/nMWOF4J.png

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, your error was:

[image: SublimeCodeIntel error]

This is an error raised by SublimeCodeIntel ([line 375](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel/blob/master/libs/codeintel2/tree_python.py#L375) of `libs/codeintel2/tree_python.py`, specifically). I'm not that familiar with the code, but from what I can tell it looks like the search engine is not getting any hits, and has nothing to expand. It may be that your code has gone beyond SublimeCodeIntel's lookup depth, because `client` is an instance of the `gdata.docs.service.DocsService()` class, `documents_feed` is `client`'s `GetDocumentListFeed()` class, and `document_entry` is an iterator for each `entry` in `documents_feed`. You are now trying to get the `title.text` attribute of `document_entry`, which is essentially

```
gdata.docs.service.DocsService().GetDocumentListFeed().entry().title.text
```

(more or less). You have a number of functions in there generating potentially a lot of data, and I would guess that SublimeCodeIntel just can't keep track of it all.